# why this panda data frame doesn't append

Tags: python, pandas

I am hoping in the following code, the for loop will loop around all the csv in the folder, and the df data frame will append after reading from each csv.  However, the df here never appends, but only contain the content of the first csv.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

We are in python 3.6 and pandas 0.21

```
    path = "/home/ubuntu/QA/client_" + CLIENT_ID + "_raw_data_" + year + "/_ACTUAL_*_Accrual*.xls"

    if CLIENT_ID in ('7')

    df_columns=pd.DataFrame(columns=['PropID','PROPERTY_CODE','TreeNodeID','ACCOUNT_CODE','TreeNodeName','ReportYear','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'])

    OUTPUT_CSV="Client_"+CLIENT_ID+"_"+year+"_"+ACCOUNTING_TYPE+"_QA.csv"

    df_columns.to_csv(OUTPUT_CSV, header=True, index=False, encoding='utf-8',na_rep="NA", mode='w')

    df = pd.DataFrame()

    for fname in glob.iglob(path):

        print (fname)

        df2 = pd.DataFrame()

        df2=pd.read_excel(fname,skiprows=4,converters={'TreeNodeCode':np.int64,'PropCode':np.str}).dropna(subset=['TreeNodeCode'],how='any') ## convert the account code in the raw data into strings. dropna drops the raw of the column 4 ,which is the IAM account code, if the column 4 is NA

        print (df2)

        df=df.append(df2)

    df=df.rename(columns={'TreeNodeCode':'ACCOUNT_CODE'})

    df=df.rename(columns={'PropCode':'PROPERTY_CODE'})

    df['PROPERTY_CODE'] = df_QA['PROPERTY_CODE'].astype(np.str)

    df['ACCOUNT_CODE'] = df_QA['ACCOUNT_CODE'].astype(np.str)

    df_QA['PROPERTY_CODE'] = df_QA['PROPERTY_CODE'].astype(np.str)

    df_QA['ACCOUNT_CODE'] = df_QA['ACCOUNT_CODE'].astype(np.str)

    print ("this is df")

    print (df)

    print ("this is df_QA")

    print (df_QA)

    df_check=pd.merge(df,df_QA, how='inner',on=['PROPERTY_CODE','ACCOUNT_CODE'])

    #print (df_check)

    # tricks in this ticket: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384192823/subtracting-multiple-columns-and-appending-results-in-pandas-dataframe

    df_check[['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']] = df_check[['Jan_x','Feb_x','Mar_x','Apr_x','May_x','Jun_x','Jul_x','Aug_x','Sep_x','Oct_x','Nov_x','Dec_x']] - df_check[['Jan_y','Feb_y','Mar_y','Apr_y','May_y','Jun_y','Jul_y','Aug_y','Sep_y','Oct_y','Nov_y','Dec_y']].values

    #print (df_check)

    df_check2=df_check[['PropID','PROPERTY_CODE','TreeNodeID','ACCOUNT_CODE','TreeNodeName','ReportYear','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']]

    #print (df_check2)

    # tricks of panda query: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html#pandas-dataframe-query

    df_check3=df_check2.query('Jan > 0 | Jan < 0 | Feb > 0 | Feb < 0 | Mar > 0 | Mar < 0 | Apr > 0 | Apr < 0 | May > 0 | May < 0 | Jun > 0 | Jun < 0 | Jul > 0 | Jul < 0 | Aug > 0 | Aug < 0 | Sep > 0 | Sep < 0 | Oct > 0 | Oct < 0 | Nov > 0 | Nov < 0 | Dec > 0 | Dec < 0')

    #print (df_check3)

    #print (df_check3.info())

    df_check3.to_csv(OUTPUT_CSV, header=False, index=False,

               na_rep="NA", mode='a')
```

Comment: Do all the csv have the same columns? can you put the first line of a couple of the csv's?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need append each DataFrame to list first and then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
dfs = []
for fname in glob.iglob(path):
    print (fname)
    df2=pd.read_excel(fname,skiprows=4,converters={'TreeNodeCode':np.int64,'PropCode':np.str}).dropna(subset=['TreeNodeCode'],how='any') ## convert the account code in the raw data into strings. dropna drops the raw of the column 4 ,which is the IAM account code, if the column 4 is NA
    print (df2)
    dfs.append(df2)

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

---

Also your code:

```
df=df.rename(columns={'TreeNodeCode':'ACCOUNT_CODE'})

df=df.rename(columns={'PropCode':'PROPERTY_CODE'})

df['PROPERTY_CODE'] = df_QA['PROPERTY_CODE'].astype(np.str)

df['ACCOUNT_CODE'] = df_QA['ACCOUNT_CODE'].astype(np.str)

df_QA['PROPERTY_CODE'] = df_QA['PROPERTY_CODE'].astype(np.str)

df_QA['ACCOUNT_CODE'] = df_QA['ACCOUNT_CODE'].astype(np.str)
```

should be simplify to:

```
df=df.rename(columns={'TreeNodeCode':'ACCOUNT_CODE', 'PropCode':'PROPERTY_CODE'})
cols = ['PROPERTY_CODE','ACCOUNT_CODE']
df_QA[cols] = df[cols] = df_QA[cols].astype(str)
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael.  But I found a weird thing: the dfs rows will be shifted in the concated df.  Each dfs rows will be shifted 1 row ahead for each PropCode.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I think it is data problem. Maybe need skiprows=3 in read_excel I guess. Are data confidental?